# Align table columns left and right

Tags: html, css, alignment, html-table

My table has 3 columns. 2 of them needs to be aligned left, and 3th one right. Can you please help me to achieve that ?

I've tried several methods and the last one I've tried is in this code, nothing works properly. Goal, what I want to achieve is that icon, which is in the last column will stays there even when somebody resizes the browser.

My HTML code is

```
            <div class="panel-meals">
                <div class="table-meals">
                     <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td>200</td>
                            <td>abc</td>
                            <td><i class="ti-exchange-vertical"></i></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>50</td>
                            <td>abc</td>
                            <td><i class="ti-exchange-vertical"></i></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>300</td>
                            <td>abc</td>
                            <td><i class="ti-exchange-vertical"></i></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>1</td>
                            <td>Lemon</td>
                            <td><i class="ti-exchange-vertical"></i></td>
                        </tr>
                     </table>   
                </div>
```

and CSS (SCSS)

```
.panel-meals {

.table-meals {
  word-spacing: 1px;
  margin-left: 151px;
  border-left: 1px solid #c6c6c6;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 13px;

  td {
    text-align: left;
    padding-left: 25px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
  }

  td:nth-child(2n+2) {
    text-align: left;
    padding-left: 37px;
  }

  td:nth-child(3n+3) {
    text-align: right;
    padding-right: 200px;
    color: $grey;
      i {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
        -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
        -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
        transform: rotate(90deg);
    }
  }
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
.table-meals {
  td { text-align: left; }
  td:nth-child(3) { text-align: right; }
}
```

to solve your problem. An alternative to `:nth-child(3)` for this specific case is to use the neighboring selector `+` instead:

```
.table-meals {
  td { text-align: left; }
  td + td + td { text-align: right; }
}
```

```css
.panel-meals .table-meals {
  word-spacing: 1px;
  margin-left: 151px;
  border-left: 1px solid #c6c6c6;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 13px;
}
.panel-meals .table-meals table {
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 100%;
}
.panel-meals .table-meals td {
  background-color: #ddd;
  text-align: left;
}
.panel-meals .table-meals td:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: #c0c0c0;  
}
.panel-meals .table-meals td:nth-child(3) {
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  text-align: right;
  color: #ddd;
}
.panel-meals .table-meals td:nth-child(3) i:after {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  content: "✔";
}
```

```html
<div class="panel-meals">
  <div class="table-meals">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>200</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td><i class="ti-exchange-vertical"></i>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>50</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td><i class="ti-exchange-vertical"></i>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>300</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td><i class="ti-exchange-vertical"></i>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Lemon</td>
        <td><i class="ti-exchange-vertical"></i>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
```

Comment: Connexo, thank you for your answer. I've tried both methods but they don't work. Icons are still in the same position, right next to their next column. 
Do you have any other ideas, how to solve this ?)

Comment: You still have that `padding-right: 200px;` on your third column?

Comment: No no, I've deleted it and instead I've tryied different paddings and margins but with either 0 or wrong effect

Comment: I've added a demonstration snippet proving that it works.

Comment: Oki, the key was also in adding 100% width to the table. Now it works perfectly. 
Thank you again :)